# Facebook share plugin is not scraping my site on first share

Tags: facebook

I have a problem whenever I try to click my share button for the first time...

It's not seeing my `og:image`, but it's seeing my site logo instead.

See: http://d.pr/i/NIQZ

But for the second share and/or second attempt of clicking the share icon again, it begins to load the correct `og:image` or rather the thumbnail.

Proof: http://d.pr/i/vWAg

Here are my meta tags:

```
            <meta property="og:image" content="http://stmaws.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/53184e19fd3401484600109b.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJQPNZH4P5E5ZY4LQ&Expires=1394388088&Signature=QTgflfyCzyIXVB%2BrMn2hBRw6srM%3D" />
            <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://stmaws.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/http://stmaws.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/53184e19fd3401484600109b.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJQPNZH4P5E5ZY4LQ&Expires=1394388088&Signature=QTgflfyCzyIXVB%2BrMn2hBRw6srM%3D.jpg" />
            <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
            <meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
            <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
            <meta property="og:title" content="Check out what I made on Muserk.com" />
            <meta property="og:site_name" content="Check out what I made on Muserk.com" />
            <meta property="og:description" content="Muserk.com gives you the ability to legally add music to your videos and share them with the world!" />
            <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.muserk.com/video/index/531a092efd3401725c00067f" />
```

The url that I want to share is: http://www.muserk.com/video/index/531a092efd3401725c00067f

Facebook Debugger tool is showing response code 200 so I can't replicate this issue.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.muserk.com%2Fvideo%2Findex%2F531a092efd3401725c00067f

Sharer link: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.muserk.com%2Fvideo%2Findex%2F531a092efd3401725c00067f

PS: I cleared my browser cache like 5 times already and got no luck.

EDITS:

In my app that uses the `sharer.php?` way of catering share buttons, how can I implement the `scrape=true` paramater. Any ideas?

Tried to add the parameter to my sharer link but didn't work

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.muserk.com%2Fvideo%2Findex%2F531a092efd3401725c00067f&scrape=true
```